# Synchronize SQLAlchemy ORM objects with external files on disk

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am using the SQLAlchemy ORM to represent the data model of a MySQL database. Suppose that for one of my ORM entity types, there is an external file of auxiliary data stored on disk, with a one-to-one association between database rows and files.

Is there a good software pattern to follow for keeping instances of the ORM objects in-sync with the external files?

For example, it would be ideal to have a way of attaching the data to an instance of the ORM object with some type of setter, which would then hold onto the data internally, and write it to disk when the object is persisted into the database.

Also, deletion of the file should happen in-sync with deletion of the ORM object from the database.

I am guessing I need to make use of the event-listener system in SQLAlchemy to register callbacks with these state transitions. But I'm not sure of the best way to do this, where the event listeners should be registered, how I can encapsulate this logic within a specific ORM entity type, and how I can store arbitrary data in an ORM entity which does not map to a database column.

Answer (score 0):

This library https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-media/ might do what you need